# How can I scale multiple objects around their own origin in 2.80?

Tags: mesh, transforms, scale, origin

I want to scale multiple objects at once, with every object using their own origin as a pivot point, instead of the center between the objects.

All answers I found so far do not apply to version 2.80.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set pivot point to *Individual Origins*.
Then each object will use it's own origin point.

[image]

Comment: Aaaaah, there is where that bugger went! Thanks a lot.